# How to add error popup for empty TextField input in Scenebuilder

Tags: javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

I am making an application using Scenebuilder with JavaFX.

I have three inputs for a `TableView`:

1. Two `TextField` `input1`, `input2`.
2. One `DatePicker`.

When one or more of the input fields is empty and i click on the `addButton`, the object is added to the `TableView`.

**How do I show an error popup which appears whenever i click on `addButton` and at least one field (`input1`, `input2`)  is empty ?**

Comment: You want to show an alert window when you click on add ? is that it ?

Comment: Yes, if any of the input boxes are empty, then a alert window should popup saying that you have to enter content in all input boxes. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        if ((input1.getText() != null && !input1.getText().isEmpty()) &&
            (input2.getText() != null && !input2.getText().isEmpty())){
            //ADD CODE TO ADD THE ITEM HERE!
        } else {
           Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
           alert.setTitle("Input fields empty");
           alert.setContentText("Please fill all input fields");

           alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
});
```

**PS :** Here you can find different [Alert Types](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) depending on your needs.